# Custom function in R raster is failing from regression in zyp package

Tags: r, r-raster

I am sorry that I can't make this reproducible, I have tried many times but I can't get the same error to pop up.

Here is my problem I have a stacked raster in R which is essentially a 3D matrix.  The shape of this stacked raster is (500, 500, 15).  I want to run a theil sen regression through every pixel in the stack which is therefore 500 regressions with 15 elements in each vector.  There can be NaN values present.

This is an example of my code:

```
libarary(raster)
library(zyp)

tsfun = function(x, na.rm){
     #if all Nan return NaN
     if all(is.na(x))){return(NaN)}
     #if less than three values are not NaN return NaN
     if length(na.omit(x)) < 3){return(NaN}
     #otherwise run the regression
     return(zyp.trend.vector(x)[["trend"]]
}

result = calc(input_stack, fun = tsfun, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but this returns:

```
Error in Kendall(t.prime[dmap.prime], ytnm) : length(x)<3 
Called from Kendall(t.prime[dmap.prime], ytnm)
```

When I get prompted to explore the error the vector it is failing on is:

```
[1] 1 2
```

I have written a workaround for vectors less than a length of 3 so I don't understand why this would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a difficult question to answer as you provide no example data. This is how I would debug it. Use a loop instead of calc, so that you can find out where it (first) fails. Inspect what is going on, fix `tsfun` and try again (perhaps starting at the last value of i).

```
result <- raster(input_stack)

j <- 1
for (i in j:ncell(input_stack)) {
    result[i] <- tsfun(input_stack[i], na.rm=TRUE)
}

j <- i
input_stack[i]
tsfun(input_stack[i])
```

fix `tsfun` and try again, re-starting at the point where it failed

```
for (i in j:ncell(input_stack)) {
    result[i] <- tsfun(input_stack[i])
}
```

I note that your function `tsfun` has a `na.rm` argument that is not used, and that it has a missing parenthesis after the second `return(NaN`. It is probably more appropriate to return `NA`. Also, the first line of code is redundant given the second line of code. It also seems to me that it can handle vectors that are mostly or all `NA` so you do not need any of that. So it can be rewritten as:

```
tsfun2 <- function(x) {
     if length(na.omit(x)) < 3) { return(NA) }
     return(zyp.trend.vector(x)[["trend"]]
}
```

Or do

```
result = calc(input_stack, fun=function(x) { zyp.trend.vector(x)[["trend"]] } )
```

For example:

```
library(raster)
library(zyp)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
ss <- stack(s, sqrt(s))
result <- calc(ss, fun=function(x) { zyp.trend.vector(x)[["trend"]] } )
```